# Apache Beam IllegalMutationException

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am running this sample code from google testing out a Spanner input into Dataflow. When I try to access a column by name I seem to be getting an `IllegalMutationException` . I am not trying to modify the input (that I am aware of at least).  If I remove the println it works just fine. It also works if I say `row.getString("fieldName")`.  Any idea why this is happening?

```
  public static class EstimateStructSizeFn extends DoFn<Struct, Long> {

@ProcessElement
public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws Exception {
  Struct row = c.element();
  System.out.println(row.getString("action"));
```

Comment: Do you get the error when you do other things? e.g. your actual business logic

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace please?